# What is {% url %} in django?

Tags: django, templates

I have Django template:

```
<form id="contactForm" method="get" action="{% url 'contact-form' %}">
...
</form>
```

What is `{% url 'contact-form' %}` ?

---

Here's urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from app.views import index, single_post, contact_form


urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("django.contrib.staticfiles.urls")),
    path("single-post/", single_post, name="single-post"),
    path("contact-form/", contact_form, name="contact-form"),
    path("", index),
]
```

What does
`path("contact-form/", contact_form, name="contact-form")`
mean?

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url)?

Comment: what is 'contact-form'? is this a reference to some url? if yes, then where can it be found?

Comment: @LoganLee: it is the name of a view, so in your `urls.py` you have some `path(.., name='contact-form')`, or `url(.., name='contact-form')`, etc.

Comment: @LoganLee: it looks like you take too much hay on your fork. Django's tutorial gives you a step-by-step introduction, such that you first understand what a path is, a view, etc. Just randomly starting somewhere is probably not the most efficient way to understand how Django works.

Answer (score 3):

To link to another page in an app, to reconstruct the URL to it using the {% url 'app_name:page_name' %} template tag with the app's name and the page's name:

The Web Framework uses namespaces to eliminate conflicts between different apps. For example, specifying {% url app1:home %} and {% url app2:home %} indicates whether the Home page belongs to app1 or app2.
The Web Framework uses the filename (without the .html extension) as the page name unless you explicitly specify a different internal name for the template in the URL mapping. For example, the name of mypage.html is "mypage" unless you set up a custom URL mapping.
For example, to link to mypage.html in the app called "myapp", use the following code in your template:

```
This is the URL for "mypage": <a href="{% url 'myapp:mypage' %}">Click here</a>\
```

Links for more reading:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 1):

`{% url 'contact-form' %}` is a way to add a link to another one of your pages in the template. `url` tells the template to look in the URLs.py file.

The thing in the quotes to the right, in this case `contact-form`, tells the template to look for something with `name=contact-form`.

`path("contact-form/", contact_form, name="contact-form")` has three components. The one closest to the right `name="contact-form"` is the name and it functions very similarly to the name of a human in that it is how that particular path is referred to.

`contact_form` tells it which block of code should be executed to open that URL once found.

`"contact-form/"` is what the URL should be on the website. Think of it like the mailing address of the view.

Answer (score 0):

It is used in template for redirecting to certain URL.

For example, if you have used "path('', views.test, name = "testurl")

Then you can use "testurl" to redirect test views.py

It is more like using 'a' tag in HTML to redirect to another page!